# getting the follwerList from the through table (sequelize)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Currently making a sns project.
Have a user model and made a N:M association which tells you who is following who.
So there is a connected models between 'user' and 'user'.

This is how my code looks like

```
static associate(db) {
    db.User.hasMany(db.Post);
    db.User.belongsToMany(db.User, {
      foreignKey: 'followingId',
      as: 'Followers',
      through: 'Follow',
    });
    db.User.belongsToMany(db.User, {
      foreignKey: 'followerId',
      as: 'Followings',
      through: 'Follow',
    });
  }
```

and I'm trying to show how many followers and following the user has at the profile page.
So what I did is when the /main pass

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.followingList = User.findAll({
    where : {followerId : req.user}
  });
  next();
});
```

Having a problem accessing the data from through table.

Having a problem accessing the data from through table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to get the user along with followings and followers then you need to use `findOne` (or `findByPk` if `req.user` is a primary key value) because we want a single user and just include both associations in the query though I don't recommend to include more than one M:N associations to the same query:

```js
 res.locals.followingList = await User.findOne({
    where : {id : req.user},
    include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'Followers'
    }, {
      model: User,
      as: 'Followings'
    }]
  });
```